# MySQL RegEx to match two consecutive digits that are the same

Tags: mysql, regex

I am using the following RegEx in MySQL to match two consecutive digits that are the same anywhere in a string:

> ^.*([[:digit:]])\1+.*$

It matches correctly the following strings:

> 8831
>   5011
>   9931

but it also matches

> 9318

and it doesn't match

> 3449

Is the problem around .* or is it something else?

Comment: I didn't know you could even back reference in MySQL's Regex. What is the `+` for?

Comment: I thought that MySQL supports backreferencing, but it turns out the opposite way :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to check to the same thing twice directly, instead you would need to check for all possibilities. Luckily since you are only looking at 10 digits, it's relatively easy:

```
(11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99|00)
```

Comment: Parenthesis seem unnecessary (and appear to be ignored).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MySQL regular expressions have back references.  You can do the more verbose:

```
where col regexp '00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99'
```